# Revolution repeated summons me soonest—what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

I thought of a riddle:

> Dethrone the king, cast out the poorest
>
> Revolution repeated summons me soonest
>
> Put the rocks in the sky and the sun in the sea
>
> Either way 'round, I'll still be me
>
> I am (mostly) in crabs, and fish, and in birds
>
> This way I am myself in these very words
>
> Fastest in each of a metronome's flicks
>
> And part of its tastiest ticks

The solution is an English word.

Answer (score 1):

These are probably wrong but here are some ideas I've had revolving around....

> EIGHT
>  King Edward VIII abdicated the throne, and King Henry VIII had bad policies casting out poor monks
>  A revolution (circle) repeated forms a figure eight
>  An eight is formed by a circle (rock) up high and a circle (sun) down low. Or the other way round
>  Crabs have 8 legs. No idea on fish/birds, hence probably wrong. Some might think octopuses are fish.  Birds is worth 8 in Scrabble.
>  'This way I am myself in these words' - these words are in 8 lines
>  A metronome can count eighth notes
>  ticks (animals tasty to birds) have 8 legs

> KERATIN
>  King dethroned = K
>  Poorest = RE if you cast out 'stoop', which is odd hence probably wrong
>  Revolution repeated = Anarchy twice = AT
>  'rocks in the sky', 'sun in the sea' both contain 'IN' with words around it
>  Crabs, fish, and birds all contain keratin, especially crabs
>  'a metronome's flicks' contains 'k e r a t i n' as a subset
>  Ticks contain keratin

> CHITIN
>  Similar to above except even more forced, so I won't elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something like

> CYCLE? (I also thought of PERIOD in the same vein).

*Dethrone the king, cast out the poorest

Revolution repeated summons me soonest*

> If the first line is a red herring, and "revolution" is meant in the sense of around a circle, then repeated revolutions could definitely lead to a cycle.

*Put the rocks in the sky and the sun in the sea

Either way 'round, I'll still be me*

> The daily cycle, sun appearing to enter the sea at sunset? (depending on where you are) Not sure about "rocks in the sky" though.

*I am (mostly) in crabs, and fish, and in birds

This way I am myself in these very words*

> Many birds and fish have migration cycles, and so do some crabs. There is some repetitive language (cycle-like?) in this very verse.

*Fastest in each of a metronome's flicks

And part of its tastiest ticks*

> A metronome is of course flicking and ticking periodically on a cycle.

Answer (score -1):

Is it?

> **Pizza**

*Dethrone the king, cast out the poorest*

> Pizza <strike>King</strike>

*Revolution repeated summons me soonest*

> The repeated revolutions for calling to order (summon) a pizza on a rotary phone.

*Put the rocks in the sky and the sun in the sea*

> Putting olives as toppings and pepperoni in a sea of cheese.

*Either way 'round, I'll still be me*

> Pizza is 360° symmetrical.

*I am (mostly) in crabs, and fish, and in bird*

*This way I am myself in these very words*

> Most pizzas are meat-based. **me** is in *meat*.

*Fastest in each of a metronome's flicks

And part of its tastiest ticks*

> *Presto* is one of the fastest metronomes. *Pesto*, which is a part of it, is one of the tastiest sauces on a pizza.